# Unable to connect to TFS server in Visual studio community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When I try to connect to a local TFS server in visual studio community 2015 Visual studio hangs and then crashes...  I've tried the following:  clearing the TFS cache, uninstalling the git plugin, disabling my AV, re-installing Visual Studio 2015...  I get to the part where I need to add the server but as soon as I click ok after entering the IP address something goes wrong.  It shows me the dialog where I have to enter my username/password and then hangs/crashes...  I use a screen reader and even though it doesn't show anything on the screen when this happens I sometimes hear windows security right before it crashes...  Any idea what else I can try?

Comment: Seems some error occurs when the credential dialog pops up. What's the version of IE on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below ways to narrow this issue:

- Try to use your account to connect TFS on another machine.
- Try to connect to TFS with another account on your machine.
- If you are using **proxy** in IE, disable the proxy and try again.
- Disable your **Antivirus software** and **Firewall** on your machine
  and try the connect again.
- Try to connect  to TFS **web portal** in IE such as `http://your
  server:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/Your GIT Project/` to see if this 
  works well.

Comment: I can connect from the browser.  If you read again my big issue is not being able to connect from Visual studio community 2015...

Comment: Asking you  to connect from the browser is trying to make sure your TFS server works well.  The configuration of TFS server is OK. Then the issue is more related to VS. Did you get any related log or error info after the hangs /crashes?

Comment: No nothing.  I uninstalled/installed VS 2013 and the same thing happens so it must be windows 10 related?